# What is efficient for updating content in real time system?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I am updating HTML page content using ajax call in every 1 second. I want to know what is the efficient way of updating the content of div. should I replace the whole div with the new one or replace the content using jquery. there are nested divs inside the main div.

Comment: Can you only use ajax call?

Comment: To your question: just replace the content. You're not going to get very "realtime" with long-polling on the web, though. At best maybe look into WebSockets.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the number of elements of your page and how complex your select queries will be. If u got a few divs which can be easily selected then you should simply replace the content of divs. If your page is complex, selecting and updating divs might be slower than having a render function which will accept data as a parameter and produce the HTML and hook it to parent div. In another word, you may want to consider treating your divs as components.

Also, you may wanna try some javascript frameworks like ReactJS or AngularJS.